# Azure DevOps 2020 licence

Tags: azure-devops

I bought a license to use Azure DevOps 2020 and a license came to use SQL Server 2019 Standard.

Where do I see how many processor core I can use on the server for this SQL Server license?

" Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Standard is included with the Azure DevOps Server license for use
with Azure DevOps Server"

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think it's a per core license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, seems this issue is not related to Azure DevOps side.

You could refer below tables which shows a comparison of the key capacity limits across the SQL Server 2019 editions.

[image]

[image]

For more detail info please refer our official doc here:

- [Microsoft SQL Server 2019  Licensing guide](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/6/0/66078040-86d8-4f6e-b0c5-e9919bbcb537/SQL%20Server%202019%20Licensing%20guide.pdf)
- [sql-server-2019-pricing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019-pricing)

Besides, suggest you directly connect with a [Microsoft solution provider](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/solution-providers/home) in order to get a more concreted idea of this area.